# Will the operation "Edit Provisioning Profile" in Apple's Member Center influences the previous Provisioning Profiles?

Tags: ios, jenkins, provisioning-profile, udid

Some iOS devices were added to my team, and I want to modify the Ad hoc provisioning profile to contain these devices' UDIDs in order to do the test.

After add UDIDs to the *Devices* part, I want to *Edit* the Ad hoc Provisioning Profile to include these UDIDs. However because this Ad hoc Provisioning Profile (current edition) is in use now, will this operation have bad influences to current Profiles? i.e. the current edition becomes invalid.

I noticed that Provisioning Profile contains the valid date information as well as the UDIDs, could I edit this file to add the UDIDs?

Because we use two Jenkins to do the build, and these Provisioning Profiles will not automatically updated to the "jenkins" user's *Provisioning Profile* folder, so if previous Provisioning Profile will be affected, I prefer to create a new one rather than edit it.

Answer (score 1):

When you edit a provisioning profile, the previous profile becomes invalid. I will advise you to create a new profile instead of editing.